# Question about an inequality during proof that $e^2$ is irrational.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

I am reading a proof of the irrationality of $e^2$ and I am stuck on the following inequality:
Let $S := -a\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} \mp ...\right)}_{S^*}$ (just because of space issues) with $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The proof I am reading states that
$$
-\frac{a}{n} < S < -a\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^3} - ...\right)}_{\tilde S} = -\frac{a}{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) < 0.
$$
Why is this true? My intuition tells me that $S^* < \frac{1}{n}$ since $1/n$ is already greater than the first term of $S^*$ and the terms afterwards all tends to 0 rather quickly so it never reaches $1/n$ but I am looking for a more rigorous explanation. The same goes for $S^*$ being apparently smaller than $\tilde S$. I see that the terms which get subtracted tends to zero more quickly than the terms of $S^*$ and so the inequality could be true as far as my intuition goes but not further. Thanks in advance for any help!
(The proof I am referring to is out of "Proofs from THE BOOK" by Martin Aigner and Günter M. Ziegler in case anyone is wondering.)

Comment: The series for $S/(-a) $ passes the Leibniz test for alternating series and hence $S/(-a) <1/(n+1)$ and $S/(-a) >\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{1}{n+2}$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for the comment! But could you please elaborate a little bit further why those inequalities are true? For example I just do not understand how we can say that $\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} \mp...\right) < \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^3} -...\right)$ since on the right we only subtract terms greater than zero from the first one but somehow this adds up to more than the left hand term although we are also adding terms there?

Comment: The inequality is not true for every $a$. It is only true for positive $a$. If you negate $a$, it is the same as multiplying through by $-1$, which will reverse both inequalities.

Comment: You should have a look at [Wiki entry on Leibniz test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Are we using the alternating series estimation theorem here?

Comment: Yes I am using that theorem in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me kind of long to understand this proof but I think I finally understood and want to share what I've learned at this point. Also I think the way I stated my question was kind of misleading so I apologize for that.
First of all we assumed that $e^2$ is in fact rational with $e^2 = \frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers (since $e^2$ is also definitely positive). We can write this equation as $bn!e = an!e^{-1}$ (we also multiplied by $n!$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N})$ and insert the definition of $e$ and $e^{-1}$ via the exponential function (in the following for $e^{-1}$ and $n$ even):
$$
e^{-1} = \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} \mp ... + \frac{1}{n!}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{(n+1)!} - \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \frac{1}{(n+3)!} \mp ...\right).
$$
Doing this the right hand side of the equation breaks up into two pieces one of which is
$$
-an!\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)!} - \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \frac{1}{(n+3)!} \mp ...\right) = -a\biggl(\underbrace{\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} \mp ...}_{S^*}\biggl).
$$
Now we want to approximate the value of $S^*$ and this is where the above inequality comes from. I think I should have made this a lot clearer in my question. As @ParamanandSingh pointed out $S^*$ passes the Leibniz-test for an alternating series. This is very useful because the value of any alternating series which passes the test can be approximated via $S^*_{2k-1} \leq S^* \leq S^*_{2k} \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ where $S^*_k$ is the $k$-th partial sum of $S^*$ hence for $k=1$ we get
$$
S^* \leq \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} < \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{2}{n}
$$
and
$$
S^* \geq \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{n+1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{n+2}.
$$
So in total we have
$$
-\frac{2a}{n} \leq -aS^* \leq -\frac{a}{n+2} < 0
$$
which is enough to conclude that for large enough $n$ the value of $-aS^*$ will lie inside the open interval $(-1, 0)$.

Answer (score -1):

For $a > 0$, if you divide through by $(-a)$, the inequality becomes
$$\frac1{n+1} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{(n+1)^k} < \frac1{n+1} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}n!}{(n+1+k)!} < \frac 1n = \frac1{n+1} - \frac{-1}{n^2 + n}$$
Or equivalently,

$$\frac{-1}{n^2 + n} < \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}n!}{(n+1+k)!} < \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{(n+1)^k} = \frac1n$$

The middle summation is alternating and the absolute value of the terms decreases to $0$ as $k \to \infty$. Thus it must converge.

If we sum the terms in pairs, each pair consists of a positive term added to a negative term of smaller size, so every partial sum is $> 0$. So the full summation is $\ge 0$. which shows the left hand inequality.

For the right hand inequality, we can rewrite the middle summation as $$\frac 1{n+1} - \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kn!}{(n+1+k)!}$$
Once again this is an alternating series of decreasing terms with positive first term, meaning the summation itself is also $> 0$, and thus the full expression is $< \frac1{n+1} < \frac 1n$. Thus the right hand inequality also holds.